# Add a "footer" to each group?

Tags: 7, views

I'd like to build a custom "Add more" link under each *group by* in a view. I'd also need the node ID of the *group by* field as a token.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this "group by" views contains node content?

Comment: Yep. Grouping content by an entity reference field.

Comment: what does "add more" button do in this case?

Comment: A link that prepopulates some taxonomy terms and also an entity reference field in an entity form with the grouping node's id.

Answer (score 0):

If you need **nid** of current node as token, then just add **Content: Nid** in field list, and check **exclude from display** before saving it. Move this field at the top of the list & you will be able to use it as token in any other field under **Rewrite Result**.

But if you want to use **nid** of **entityreference** field as token, then you need to a **Relationship** under **Advance** tab in your view. Then after follow the same process which I explained in first paragraph. But this time you will have to use your added relationship.

For custom **Add More** link, just add **Global: Custom text** in field list & put HTML for this Add More link.

Comment: That adds custom text to each row but I need it after each group. However, adding a custom field and using it for grouping nr.2 gives what I need but above the group. I need it below the grouping.

Comment: @NiallMurphy - I am unable to understand your requirement about placing. Is adding something into views footer would work for you?

Comment: If there are 100 rows, then there are 10 groups of 10 rows. I need to add a "pseudo footer" after each group of 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by overriding Style Output plugin for your view by copying the default template `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` to your theme's folder and renaming it to `views-view-unformatted--your-view-machine-name.tpl.php` (machine name of the view is used, so that only the particular view is overridden).

then you could do something like this in the template (comments included):

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
    <!-- H3 outputs the title of the group -->
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!-- adding footer to each group --> 
<div class="view-group-footer">
    <?php 
        // $id is the number of the view row
        // each row will have data of the entity_refence field as it is used for grouping
        // we need to grab the target_id (node ID) of the entity that is used to form the group
        // because the target_id of each row inside the group will be the same - we only need to grab it once and then form the custom link
        // so we grab it from the last row of the group, otherwise we would grab it inside the foreach loop

        $last_row_in_group = $view->result[$id];

        // NOTE: "field_field_entity_reference" has extra 'field_' prefix at the begining followed by the actual machine name of the entity reference field
        print '<a href="your_url_'.$last_row_in_group->field_field_entity_reference[0]['raw']['target_id'].'">add more</a>';
  ?>
</div>
```

*PS. the link should be generated with l() function, I placed < a > tag in the code as a quick example.*

Comment: @NiallMurphy did you find this approach effective to your needs?

Comment: I had a look and your code looks good.. But I'm using the views_pivot module. I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to tpl files and the views_pivot tpl looks very complicated to me. Putting it off till the weekend!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I just had to do this same thing - but for Drupal 8. Here's a twig version of the 'if last row' solution above, placed in the while loop of the same file name as in the example above:

```
{% if loop.last %}
    {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row-last',
    ]
   <!-- or whatever you need to do to the last row -->
    %}
%}
```